# Pass variable in link to modal window

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I have a modal which opens with a button currently and cannot seem to figure out how to pass variables to it to populate dynamic data from my database. I have a couple of variables in a URL that needs sent to the modal.

What I really need to do is replace the button that opens the modal with an href link.

```html
    Modal
<!---BUTTON THAT OPENS MODAL--->

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>

<!---END BUTTON--->

<!---MODAL--->
     <div id="id01" class="modal">
     <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
     <div class="container">

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
     <button type="button"  onclick="document.getElementById('id01')
     .style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>

<!---END MODAL--->

This is what I need to open the modal with (or similar) and pass the variables to it. 

    <a href="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#?viewas=#dtDay#&id=#qEventSub.id#" title="#DateFormat( dtDay, "mmmm d, yyyy" )#" style="color: white;"onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;>#Day( dtDay )#</a>
```

Comment: What you mean by _sent to the modal_ ?? how/where you will use them?

Answer (score 0):

I KNOW THIS! I had this problem :)

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Comments-<?php echo $job_numb;?>">Comments</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="Comments-<?php echo $job_numb;?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Comments for <?php echo html_entity_decode($job_name) . "&nbsp;|&nbsp;" . $job_numb;?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><?php echo html_entity_decode(nl2br($comments));?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

See, what I did was call the $job_numb, which is generated by the SQL for each record and pass that through to the modal. SO the loop creates a unique ID for each modal.

Comment: HA HA I just realize that is for Javascript. But the same principle appplies here. Just append your `id` with the variable.